# VirtualBox can't boot my ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine

[image: My screen]

This is what my screen shows, I tried multiple times, but every time, it just stagnated here.

It worked last night, and I don't know what happens.

Comment: It seems like it's booting to me, just that it's presenting you without a logon prompt via the `Not Listed?`. Are you able to click `Not Listed?`/Hit Enter to logon? You presumably had a user account as of last night.

Comment: Yeah, I had a user account, and before today, everything works fine. It seems stagnating there, and I can't hit anything, or even move my cursor.